# Notepad++ how to copy text \folder1\folder2\ and append to end of line using RegEx?

Tags: notepad++

I am using **Notepad++** to edit a batch script in which I am trying to append 2 of the folder names on each line to the end of the line with a " as Folder2 sometimes has spaces.  Folder1 is a date and Folder2 is a name.

To be clear I am looking for a way to do this in Notepad++ I think I can use Find and Replace with RegEx but don't know the correct sytax or if it can be done in Notepad++.

```
explexe "D:\I Drive\XY0\01022008\FIRST_LAST\0000\1.3.12.2.1107.5.1.4" "D:\I Drive\dump
explexe "D:\I Drive\XY0\01162008\FIRST,_LAST\0000\1.2.392.200036.912.2196110" "D:\I Drive\dump
explexe "D:\I Drive\XY0\04092008\FIRST_LAST___\0000\1.2.840.113680.5.1199306167.113468" "D:\I Drive\dump
```

I need it to look like this.

```
explexe "D:\I Drive\XY0\01022008\FIRST_LAST\0000\1.3.12.2.1107.5.1.4" "D:\I Drive\dump\01022008\FIRST_LAST\"
explexe "D:\I Drive\XY0\01162008\FIRST,_LAST\0000\1.2.392.200036.912.2196110" "D:\I Drive\dump\01162008\FIRST,_LAST\"
explexe "D:\I Drive\XY0\04092008\FIRST_LAST___\0000\1.2.840.113680.5.1199306167.113468" "D:\I Drive\dump\04092008\FIRST_LAST___\"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated I am new to Notepad++!

Comment: How does it not have any relation to the subject?  I need to know how to do this in Notepad++ since that's what I am using to edit the script.  This isn't a scripting question...

Maybe this can be solved by scripting, I don't really care about that I want to know how to do the above in Notepad++.

Comment: The OP is trying to use Notepad++ to replace text in a batch file they are editing. This is not a question about how to do something in a Windows batch file.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+?(\\\d{8})\\([^\\]+\\).+$`
- Replace with: `$0$1__$2"`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
  .+?       : 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  (         : start group 1
    \\      : a backslash (must be escaped because it has special meaning in a regex)
    \d{8}   : 8 digits (I guess it is a date)
  )         : end group 1
  \\        : a backslash
  (         : start group 2
    [^\\]+  : 1 or more any character that is not a backslash
    \\      : a backslash
  )         : end group 2
  .+        : 1 or more any character but newline
$           : end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0      : content of whole match, the entire line
$1      : content of group 1
__      : 2 underscores
$2      : content of group 2
"       : literally double quote
```

- *check Wrap around*
- *Check regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*

**Result for given example:**

```
explexe "D:\I Drive\XY0\01022008\FIRST_LAST\0000\1.3.12.2.1107.5.1.4" "D:\I Drive\dump\01022008__FIRST_LAST\"
explexe "D:\I Drive\XY0\01162008\FIRST,_LAST\0000\1.2.392.200036.912.2196110" "D:\I Drive\dump\01162008__FIRST,_LAST\"
explexe "D:\I Drive\XY0\04092008\FIRST_LAST___\0000\1.2.840.113680.5.1199306167.113468" "D:\I Drive\dump\04092008__FIRST_LAST___\"
```

Comment: Thank You Toto!  This will help a lot as there are 81,828 lines that has to be edited, there are 5 more drives with around as many lines that need to get edited as well.  You have been a great help, Thank You!

Comment: Instead of appending the 2 directories at the end of the line like this.  **D:\I Drive\dump\01022008\FIRST_LAST\"**  Can I instead combine those 2 directories separated by __ like this?  **D:\I Drive\dump\01022008__FIRST_LAST\"**